# How to evaluate user's input in s loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, operator-keyword, evaluation

I'm new in coding or programming so I hope for respect.

How can I create a program that continually accepts input from the user. The input shall be in this format operatornumber like -3

Like

```
num = 0

while((a := input("Enter operatornumber like -9;")) != "-0"):
    if (len(a) >= 2) and (a[0] in "/*-+"):
        num = eval(f"{num}{a}")
    else:
        print("Invalid input, try again.")
    
print(num)
```

But how can I make the first input of the user to only use the add (+) or subtract(-) operators but in the next input they can now use the other operators.

Like

Enter operatornumber like -9; +9
Enter operatornumber like -9; -8
Enter operatornumber like -9; -0
1

And how can I combine all the input like
+9-9 is 1?

Comment: To add to @bituniverse's answer, the `while` keyword has to be in lower case, and you need to indent the code under it.

Comment: Oohh Thank you,but I want the user's input to be in this kind of format "-9' or "+8" I want it with an operator first then will be followed by a number. Then when the user input "-0" it will compute all the user's input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the input statement, you're closing the "Enter operator and number like" msg. This is creating more problems after that line, where all green parts are considered as string now. Also, in while statement, "w" should be small letter, python is case sensitive. Try doing this:

```
Number = input("Enter operator and number like '-9' ")
Operator = ("+","-","/")
while Number == (Operator + Number):
    if Number == "-0":
        Total = 0
        Total += Number 
print(f"the result of {num} is {total} ")
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it but it still doesn't work. Whether the user input "a" or anything it still continue but I want it to stop if the input is not in this kind of format, "-8".

Comment: Well can you tell me the aim of the program, I may design a new one for you and explain it as well

Comment: It's a calculator that calculates all the users input in a loop.

Comment: Ok, so you've to always do the operations in given order, +, -, /, *?? Thr user has to only give the input right??

Comment: No, it can be in any order except the first input.

Comment: I got it, I'll write another answer, please check that

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes for the text and single quotes for the number, so they don't close each other.
You can get input forever using following code:

```
while True:
   Number = input("Enter operator and number like '-9'")
   # Place your next code here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer. We have to take input from user with operator as well, so len(<user_input<) should be >=2. Now, we'll take another variable h in which we'll traverse the string from index 1 to end, which means the operator gets removed and we'll convert it into int. Then we'll put if condition in which we'll check the user_input[0] is +,-,*,/ and then acc to that, we'll update the result. We'll ask the user whether he wants more operations or no, if y, then keep asking, else, break the while loop. Here's my code:

```
result=0
while True:
    a=input("Enter operator and number= ")
    if len(a)>=2 and a[0] in ["+","-","*","/"]:
        h=int(a[1::])
        if a[0]=="+":
            result+=h
        elif a[0]=="-":
            result-=h
        elif a[0]=="*":
            result*=h
        elif a[0]=="/":
            result/=h
        else:
            print("choose only from +-/*")
    else:
        print("invalid input")
    ch=input("Enter more?")
    if ch=='n':
        break

print(f"The result is {result}")
```

Check for indentation errors because I've copied and pasted it so it may have indentation errors

Comment: Happy to help, please upvote

Comment: Oh right hehe